# Avoid checking "\notrun" examples when using R CMD check

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

When I run `R CMD check` on my package (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in RStudio ), it also tests if my examples run without errors.

Unfortunately, there are some examples that should not be run in this context, as they involve external files that are relevant for understanding but not for testing. These are wrapped with `\dontrun{}` in the ROxygen header.

I know I could use the `--no-examples` in the `R CMD check` additional options (RStudio > Build > More > Configure Build Tools), but this would test no example at all, which is not what I want.

Instead, I'd like `R CMD check` to run `devtools::run_examples(run=FALSE, fresh = T)`, so that examples in `\dontrun{}` are not ran. This command runs perfectly in the console.

How can I configure `R CMD check` in RStudio this way?

Comment: This is strange. `\dontrun{}` should mark examples for not being tested (and this works in my experience). Maybe try running `roxygen2::roxygenise(clean = TRUE)` to delete old files. Could be that there is old code left there somewhere.

Comment: @JBGruber this is very surprising but `roxygen2::roxygenise(clean = TRUE)` did resolve the problem -_- You can post this as an answer so I can accept it and close this question.

Comment: Great! I'm not really sure when `roxygen2` leaves old code behind but I started to use this as default (as my packages don't have extensive compilation to do before documentation anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when you change documentation, such as examples, the old files remain in the `man` folder of your package. This is why after a change such as wrapping examples in `\dontrun{}`, it can make sense to clean up the directory. You can do so with `roxygen2` by running:

```
roxygen2::roxygenise(clean = TRUE)
```